# Linear algebra application in Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra

I am learning Linear Algebra(started recently) and was curious to know its applications in Machine Learning, where can I read about this

Thank you

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=linear+algebra+machine+learning

Comment: Machine learning algorithms require a sophisticated understanding of linear algebra, and familiarity with distribution and manipulation of data in n-dimensional space. Quoting a bit of the **first** problem setup from page 10 of [ESL](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/), "Matrices are represented by bold uppercase letters; for example, a
set of N input p-vectors xi
, i = 1, . . . , N would be represented by the N ×p
matrix X"

Comment: @Blender nowadays, funnily enough, this question is one of the top results for that search query.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Linear Algebra provides the computational engine for the majority of Machine Learning algorithms.

For instance, probably the most conspicuous and most frequent application of ML
is the recommendation engine.

Aside from data retrieval, the real crux of these algorithms is often
'reconstruction' of the ridiculously sparse data used as input for these engines. 
The raw data supplied to Amazon.com's user-based R/E is (probably) a massive 
data matrix in which the users are the rows and its products are represented
in the columns. Therefore, to organically populate this matrix, every customer would have to 
purchase every product Amazon.com sells. Linear Algebra-based techniques are used here.

All of the techniques in current use involve some type of ***matrix decomposition***, a fundamental
class of linear algebra techniques (e.g., [non-negative matrix approximation](http://www.mitpressjournals.org/toc/neco/19/3), and
[positive-maximum-margin-matrix approximation](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~nati/Publications/MMMFnips04.pdf) (warning link to pdf!) are perhaps the two most common)

Second, many if not most ML techniques rely on a numerical optimization technique. 
E.g., most supervised ML algorithms involve creation of a trained classifier/regressor by minimizing the delta between the value calculated by the nascent classifier and
the actual value from the training data. This can be done either iteratively or using linear algebra
techniques. If the latter, then the technique is usually ***SVD*** or some variant.

Third, the ***spectral-based decompositions***--PCA (principal component analysis) 
and kernel PCA--are perhaps the most commonly used dimension-reduction techniques, 
often applied in a pre-processing step just ahead of the ML algorithm in the data flow,
for instance, PCA is often used instance in a Kohonen Map to initialize the 
lattice. The principal insight underneath these techniques is that the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix (a square, symmetric matrix with zeros down the main diagonal, prepared from the original data matrix) are unit length and are orthogonal to each other.

Answer (score 3):

In machine learning, we generally deal with data in form of vectors/matrices. Any statistical method used involves linear algebra as its integral part. Also, it is useful in data mining.
[SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) and [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) are famous dimensionality reduction techniques involving linear algebra.
Bayesian decision theory also involves significant amount of LA.You can try  it also.

Answer (score 2):

Singular value decomposition (SVD), is a classic method widely used in Machine Learning.

I find this article is fairly easy, explaining a SVD based recommendation system, see http://www.igvita.com/2007/01/15/svd-recommendation-system-in-ruby/ .

And Strang's linear algebra book, contains a section on the application of SVD to rank web pages (HITS algorithm) see [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?id=Gv4pCVyoUVYC&lpg=PA358&ots=SW8-m_C8TI&dq=strang%20linear%20algebra%20hits%20svd&pg=PA358#v=onepage&q&f=false).